# Iterparse namespace

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following:

```
node = etree.fromstring(res.content)
items = node.xpath('v:Items/v:Item', namespaces={'v':'http://schemas.microsoft.com/eds/2012/05/01/eds'})
```

How would I do the following using `iterparse`? For example:

```
contentBuffer=io.BytesIO(res.content)
items = ET.iterparse(contentBuffer,tag='v:Items/v:Item') # <== namespace??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the fully qualified tag name using [Clark notation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces):

```
items = ET.iterparse(contentBuffer, 
                     tag='{http://schemas.microsoft.com/eds/2012/05/01/eds}Item')
```

Using a wildcard for the namespace is also possible:

```
items = ET.iterparse(contentBuffer, tag='{*}Item')
```

(Note that you cannot use `tag='{*}Items/{*}Item'`. The `tag` argument should be a tag name, not an expression.)